# Predict near future data from another correlated data source that varies quicker

Tags: time-series, correlation, neural-networks

I'm trying to figure out a way to predict the evolution of some data in the near future by using another data source that is correlated to that one but that varies quicker.

For instance, I have the oil barrel prices, and I know that if they increase, soon after the gas prices at auto-pumps are going to increase by a certain amount as well. So I'm trying to calculate the gas prices 7 days in the future, by using the oil barrel prices today (or even the oil barrel prices for the last week or last month).

My first approach was to use a Neural Network to solve the problem. It works satisfactorily, but it's very cumbersome and I believe there should be an easier and simpler way.

Comment: Well, mate, basically you are asking on the internet to give you a way of making essentially infinite amount of money. Think about it :)  Also questions which are so broad are discouraged as it would take a PhD dissertation or a few books to actually answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try a vector autoregressive (VAR) model for this problem. The VAR allows you to regress you dependent variable on past values of itself and other variables. For example, if $Y_t$ is your gas price at time $t$, and $X$ is the oil price at time $t$, you can fit the model,
$$Y_t=\beta_0+\beta_{1,Y}Y_{t-1}+\beta_{1,X}X_{t-1}+\cdots+\beta_{p,Y}Y_{t-p}+\beta_{p,X}X_{t-p}+\epsilon_t.$$

If you know that the gas price depends on the past values of the oil price, including the past oil prices should improve your prediction. The VAR model assumes stationarity and, I suspect that both variables in the example are not stationary and suggest unit root testing, and potentially modelling the differences ($\Delta Y = Y_{t}-Y_{t-1}$ and $\Delta X = X_{t}-X_{t-1}$). Good luck!